# Return NULL from a C++ template

Tags: c++, class, templates, null

I have to create a template function that searches an element in a map variable. If the element exists, the function must return it. Otherwise it must return NULL.

```
template <class K, class E> E dictionary<K,E>::research(K key) {

// map<K,E> elements;

if(elements.find(key) != elements.end()) {
    return elements.find(key)->second;
} else {
    return NULL;
}
```

Since the return type is E, returning NULL gives me always an error. How can I make this work? Or I have to structure my function differently?

This is a school homework assignment and I must return NULL, no alternatives. I'd personally do differently if I could.

Comment: If `NULL` isn't compatible with the element's type, then it can't possibly work.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: return a pointer to E: `template <class K, class E> *E dictionary<K,E>::research(K key){`

Comment: @mah, A pointer is what I'm guessing the assignment wants.

Comment: @BrianCain i edited my question, sorry i wasn't so clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The design of this function is incorrect. It is perfectly possible that `NULL` is simply incompatible with the type `E`. For instance, suppose that `E` is a struct, or a `std::string` and so on.

> This is a school homework assignment and I must return `NULL`, no alternatives.

Either your homework assignment is incorrect, or you have misunderstood its requirements. It is possible that you are expected to return a pointer to `E`?

Comment: What you say about type incompatibility is correct and it's the reason I asked here. The assignment doesn't specify anything about pointers but I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning pointers, you could consider returning something like boost::optional, i.e. a type that is either set to contain a valid object or in an invalid state. That mimics a pointer in some way, but is more explicit

The following is just to show the principle, the implementation can for sure be optimized.

```
template<typename T> class Optional {
public:
   Optional(E e): 
      isValid(true),
      mValue(e)
   {}

   Optional(): isValid(false), mValue() {}

   bool isDefined() const {return isValid;}

   E getOrElse(E const& other) const {return (isValid) ? (mValue) : (other);}

   E get(E const {return mValue;} 
private:
    bool isValid;
    T mValue;
};
```